# Configure geth to work with Ropsten

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets, ropsten

I am trying to make geth work with ropsten but I am not sure why its refusing to load my ropsten funds.

I have a ropsten account which I have imported to geth via its private key:

```
geth --testnet account import "C:\Wallet\Ropsten.txt"
```

The account was created in MetaMask and currently has 5.783 ropsten ether.

Now when I start geth in RPC mode with --testnet

```
 geth --rpcapi eth,web3,personal --testnet --rpc
```

Then when I try to check my balances using web3.js, I always get my balance as 0:

```
 web3.personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.accounts[0],"<password>", 15000);
 console.log(web3.eth.getBalance(web3.eth.accounts[0]).toNumber());
```

This always gives me 0;

I also tried specifying the ropsten bootnode manually:

```
geth --rpcapi eth,web3,personal --testnet --fast --bootnodes "enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a
40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303,eno
de://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677
ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303" --rpc
```

but still it is not loading my balance which leads me to believe that its not connected to ropsten or I am doing something wrong.

How can I make geth work with ropsten?

Comment: Is the node fully synchronized? What does `eth.blockNumber` returns? Are you sure the account was imported correctly?

Comment: Not sure what was going on. I deleted the data directory and resynced and now its working fine.